# customize bot framework web chat

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I've cloned the Microsoft Bot Framework WebChat repo and am able to build it. But I'm having hard time viewing the changes that I made.

> npm start

starts the server on a local port, but it does not display the webchat. Instead it shows the files from the project. I'm a bit familiar with Angular but I don't have any knowledge on React. I've a bot built on Python and registered on Bot Channel registration in Azure.

How do I start the webchat locally to view the changes that I've made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you left the samples in the repo on you local machine, you would need to go to `localhost:8000/samples/{sample name}` or just click the appropriate path from the files you see.

In the react sample is says this as well:

```
  1. Build the project: "npm run build"
  2. Start a web server: "npm run start"
  3. Aim your browser at "http://localhost:8000/samples?[parameters as listed below]"

  For ease of testing, several parameters can be set in the query string:
    * s = Direct Line secret, or
    * t = Direct Line token (obtained by calling Direct Line's Generate Token)
    * domain = optionally, the URL of an alternate Direct Line endpoint
    * webSocket = set to 'true' to use WebSocket to receive messages (currently defaults to false)
    * userid, username = id (and optionally name) of bot user
    * botid, botname = id (and optionally name) of bot
```

Comment: I've made some adjustments to the webchat. Do you have any guide on building and deploying this to azure ?

Comment: There are [instructions in the readme](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat) on how to build it.